# MySQL select from multiple columns but return one row

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select data from multiple rows but to have the results returned in one row.
Here is some sample data

```
baseWord  word     case 
run       ran      past
run       runners  plural
talk      talked   past
talk      talkers  plural
```

If I wanted to select the past and plural tense of the word run then I could do a union select but if I said
`SELECT baseWord, word, case FROM myTable WHERE baseWord = 'run';`
then I would get

```
baseWord word      case
run      ran       past
run      runners   plural
```

but I do not want this. I want a select statement that will return

```
baseWord, word, case, plural
run       ran   past  runners
```

so basically I would need to put the word runners in the plural column where the two baseWords are the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by joining the table to itself.
I gave the tables an alias name of one and two and then joined them

```
SELECT one.baseWord as base, one.word as word, one.case as case, two.word as plural
FROM myTable one
JOIN
myTable two ON one.baseword = two.baseWord
WHERE one.case = 'past' AND two.case = 'plural';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT baseWord,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `case` = 'past' THEN word END) word,
       'past' `case`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `case` = 'plural' THEN word END) plural
FROM myTable
WHERE baseWord = 'run'
```

Or for all the words:

```
SELECT baseWord,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `case` = 'past' THEN word END) word,
       'past' `case`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `case` = 'plural' THEN word END) plural
FROM myTable
GROUP BY baseWord
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a427d8b5fcb10150c10540f927777704).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT x.*,y.word as plural from (SELECT baseWord, word, `case` FROM myTable WHERE baseWord = 'run' and `case`='past')x join myTable y on x.baseWord=y.baseWord and y.`case`='plural';
```

If you want to do this for all the words, then:

```
SELECT x.*,y.word as plural from (SELECT baseWord, word, `case` FROM myTable WHERE `case`='past')x join myTable y on x.baseWord=y.baseWord and y.`case`='plural' group by 1,2,3,4;
```